# How to select an element from a dropdown(checkbox list)

Tags: python, selenium

I need to be able to select one item from a dropdown list (the items in the list are checkboxes) but I cannot seem to get the code correct. The web page is an internal site so I cannot provide the actual link, however here are they Elements:

To activate the dropdown list:

```
<input name="m_sqlRsWebPart$ctl00$ctl19$ctl06$ctl09$txtValue" type="text" size="28" readonly="readonly" id="m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_txtValue" title="Support Group report parameter" class="null">
```

The item from the list I need is:

```
<input id="m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_divDropDown_ctl184" type="checkbox" name="m_sqlRsWebPart$ctl00$ctl19$ctl06$ctl09$divDropDown$ctl184" onclick="$get('m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'm_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_divDropDown_ctl00');">
```

What I have tried so far is(snippet):

```
driver.find_element_by_name("m_sqlRsWebPart$ctl00$ctl19$ctl06$ctl09$txtValue").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_divDropDown_ctl184").click()
```

Does not do anything.

Full HTML for the list box:

```
<div onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="white-space:nowrap;">
<input name="m_sqlRsWebPart$ctl00$ctl19$ctl06$ctl09$txtValue" type="text" size="28" readonly="readonly" id="m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_txtValue" title="Support Group report parameter" class="null"><input src="/sites/pa/reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebPart.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.5058.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.MultiValueSelect.gif" name="m_sqlRsWebPart$ctl00$ctl19$ctl06$ctl09$ddDropDownButton" type="image" id="m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_ddDropDownButton" alt="Select a value" title="Select a value" style="vertical-align:top;cursor:pointer;">
</div>
```

Comment: it does nothing? Does it throw a `NoSuchElementException` or does it just not make the selection you want? Have you tried just executing the javascript via Selenium with `driver.execute_script("$get('m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'm_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ctl19_ctl06_ctl09_divDropDown_ctl00');")`

Comment: It just does not make the selection I want - and I'm using python

Comment: I'm just trying to get context; how does clicking the text input activate the drop down menu? It's just hard to tell from just the element how that would be possible. If it isn't actually activating the drop down menu, it is possible that the element you are trying to select from the drop down is still hidden, which would be a good explanation as to why Selenium cannot find it.

Comment: If your *dropdown* is suggestions list: try to send some characters into input field as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="text"]').send_keys('some text')`- this should *activate the dropdown*. You can also share little more HTML to make issue clearer

Comment: and what is the error message you are getting? Did you added some implicit wait?

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I'm fairly new to Python - and brand new to HTML and Selenium - but to (hopefully) answer your question. The drop down list is not a traditional drop down, in which I can type an "A" into the box and it will take me to those elements that start with A. I cannot type into the box at all. However, clicking on it will display the list of elements that can be selected - it is of type <div - if that makes a difference.

Comment: Essentially, the list box will not accept any text - typing into it does nothing - it is only activated by clicking into the list box itself or clicking the arrow next to the box

Comment: No error message at all - it just does not click on the list box once the page is fully open

Comment: @Anderson - After trying your changes, I got the following error:        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visi
ble
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5b
a8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
                                                                                                                                                                      This may be what RageCage was speaking of

Comment: did you try activating it via javascript using `driver.execute_script`?

Comment: I have not tried that - can you elaborate on what the syntax is for that?

Comment: @I.T. Guy That is the exception I would expect to see if an element is hidden in the DOM. Is that failing on the line where you send the keys or the line where you try to select the dropdown menu element?

Comment: On the line where i select/click the dropdown menu element